# ruby on rails accessing custom class attributes from its object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a custom class in my application controller. Like below:

```
class Defaults
  def initialize
    @value_1 = "1234"
    @value_2 = nil
    @data = Data.new
  end
end

class Data
   def initialize
     @data_1 = nil
   end
end
```

Now in my controller method i have created an object of type Defaults

```
def updateDefaultValues
  defaults = Defaults.new

  # i am unable to update the value, it says undefined method
  defaults.value_2 = Table.maximum("price") 
  defaults.data.data_1 = defaults.value_2 * 0.3

end
```

How to access value_2 from defaults object?

```
defaults.value_2
```

Also, how to access data_1 attribute from data object within defaults object?

```
defaults.data.data_1
```

Comment: You can't name your variable `def` - it's keyword reserved for method definitions.

Comment: For illustrating i just used as def. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`attr_accessor`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor):

```
class Defaults
  attr_accessor :value_1, :value_2, :data
  # ...
end
defaults = Defaults.new
defaults.value_1 = 1
# => 1
defaults.value_1
# => 1
```

Comment: BTW, it's very basic stuff, so I advice you to go through some Ruby tutorial.

Comment: Good choice @user3752389 :)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `def` as a keyword to define the method, that means `def` is a reserved keyword. You can't use reserved keywords as a variable.

You just need to rename your variable name from `def` to `something_else` and it should work! Your code will look like this:

```
def updateDefaultValues
  obj = Defaults.new
  obj.value_2 = Table.maximum("price") 
  obj.data.data_1
end
```

**EDIT:**

**As per OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648859/ruby-on-rails-accessing-custom-class-attributes-from-its-object#comment47437680_29648942) & updated question, he had used `def` just as an example, here is the updated answer:**

You may need [attr_accessor](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor) to make attrs accessible:

```
class Defaults
  attr_accessor :value_1, :value_2, :data

  ...
  ...
end

class Data
  attr_accessor :data_1

  ...
  ...
end
```

Comment: For illustrating i just used as def. I have updated my question.

Answer (score -1):

Add `value_2` method in Defaults class

```
class Defaults
  def initialize
    @value_1 = "1234"
    @value_2 = nil
    @data = Data.new
  end

  def value_2
    @value_2
  end
end

class Data
   def initialize
     @data_1 = nil
   end
end
```

Comment: What's the advantage of adding this method by hand?